# How to call sagas in order on component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

**problem**

I want to call `func()` when I press a `increase_number and decrease_number` button, but I don't know how to do that.

Can I do that? (It increases a number and then decreases.)

Or do I have to create a new action and saga?

Thanks for reading !

**source code**

Redux(with sagas)

```
import { createAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { all, put, select, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export const action_creators = {
    increase_number: createAction('increase_number'),
    decrease_number: createAction('decrease_number'),
    set_number_success: createAction('set_number_success')
};

const state = {
    number: 0
}

function* increase_number () {
    const state = yield select((state) => state);
    yield delay(1000);
    yield put(action_creators.set_number_success({ number:++state.number }));
}

function* decrease_number() {
    const state = yield select((state) => state);
    yield put(action_creators.set_number_success({ number:--state.number }));
}

export function* saga() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery('increase_number', increase_number),
        takeEvery('decrease_number', decrease_number)
    ]);
}

export default handleActions({
    set_number_success: (state, action) => {
        const new_number = action.payload.number;
        console.log(new_number);
        return { ...state, number:new_number };
    }
}, state);
```

Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { put, take } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { action_creators } from './redux';

function* func () {
    yield put(action_creators.increase_number());
    yield take(action_creators.set_number_success());
    yield put(action_creators.decrease_number());
}

class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return [
            <div>{this.props.number}</div>,
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.increase_number()}>increase_number</button>,
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.decrease_number()}>decrease_number</button>,
            <button type="button">increase_number and decrease_number</button> <= Here.
        ]
    }
}

function map_state_to_props(state) {
    return {
        number: state.number
    }
}

function map_dispatch_to_props(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        increase_number: action_creators.increase_number,
        decrease_number: action_creators.decrease_number
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(map_state_to_props, map_dispatch_to_props)(App);
```

[URL for test](https://codesandbox.io/s/18v577kl9j)

Comment: btw is `yield all([takeEvery` on purpose? What is the reason behind?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I don't understand what that means.. It's to call multiple operations in parallel. But is it unnecessary because they're takeEvery()? If there's any better way, please let me know. Thank you for checking out. :)

Comment: nevermind, it's valid it's the same thing as writing 2 yield successive 
 `yield` statements here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `func` should be in saga not in component, since it's a saga.

Secondly, yes you need a separate action, since it's a separate side effect, which combines 2 other side effects, but still.

You can achieve that the simplest by adding another `takeEvery()`:

```
...

function* increase_and_decrease() {
  yield call(increase);
  yield call(decrease);
}


export function* saga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery('increase_number', increase_number),
    takeEvery('decrease_number', decrease_number),
    takeEvery('incerase_and_decrease', increase_and_decrease);
  ]);
}
```

And the remaining is to pull the new action in your component into `mapDispatchToProps` and call on button click.

Comment: @leftclick glad to help